# ActiveX combobox issues

Tags: excel, vba

1) Created activex combo box to call macros with each drop down of it .

2) let say combo box as two drop down a) compare data b) clear content .

3) when I click on compare data in combo box, it  should call macro named "compare data"  else it should call macro named " clear content ".

4) to execute the same I write below code

```
Private sub combobox21_click()
  Dim a As string 
  If sheet.Combobox 21.value = " comparedata" then
    Call module1.comparedata
  Else 
    Call module1.clearcontent
  End If 
End sub
```

5) code is executing without error .but when I clicking on combobox drop down .. respective action of macro is not happening .n any error is also not coming .

Comment: While editing I found some useless space characters in your code, i.e. `compare data` should be `comparedata`; `combobox 21_ click ()
 should be `combobox21_click()` etc. Please make sure of posting your real actual code so that we can proceed from there.

Comment: Hint: Is your name `Kusum Sirole` or `kusumsirole`? Logic applies to `Combobox 21` and `" comparedata"`

Comment: Also is your combobox an ActiveX Control or a Form Control?

Comment: 1) there is no space in compare data  and combobox 21

Comment: 1) it's an active x combobox .

Comment: In your combobox drop down, what do you see? "Compare Data" or "comparedata"?

Comment: My topic headline shows that it related with activex combo box

Comment: Conparedata only ... no spaces

Comment: Code is working while debugging ..but when I click on drop down of combobox. ..It does not work

Comment: You need to understand that when you are doing string comparison then "Comparedata" <> "comparedata"... or "comparedata" <> "    comparedata". Can you attach a screenshot of your combobox with it's dropdown?

Comment: I m.not able to attach screenshot but code is  working when I run the code manually .... e.g I select drop down "comparedata" in combo box n execute the code manually ... It gives comparison result .n until I change the drop down to "clearcontent"  .the value of combox would be "comparedata" (in code)It won't work no.matter how many times I run code manually.

Comment: the moment I select "clearcontent" in drop down and run the code it will clear the screen . And now value of combox changed to "clearcontent"(in code).